# Reduce spacing between chips using multi_select_flutter

Tags: flutter

I am using the [multi_select_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/multi_select_flutter) package to create a MultiSelectChipField.
I have the following code displaying a row of circles as my chips.

```
                            Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            MultiSelectChipField(
                              chipShape: CircleBorder(
                                side: BorderSide(width: 1),
                              ),
                              items: daysOfWeek.entries
                                  .map((entry) => MultiSelectItem(
                                      entry.value, entry.key))
                                  .toList(),
                              initialValue: [],
                              showHeader: false,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(border: null),
                              selectedTextStyle:
                                  TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                              textStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                              selectedChipColor: AppColors.secondaryColor,
                              scroll: false,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
```

The above is causing an overflow and I want to reduce the spacing between each chip but don't see how. How can the spacing be reduced? I want all the chips on a single row and not to wrap them.

Here is a sample of the result and arrows indicating the spacing I am trying to reduce.

[image]

Comment: If you want a single row with no wrapping I would suggest using the scroll functionality of the package. As for the spacing... the code of the package sets padding to 0 if the scroll is enabled.

Comment: @SilkeNL I tried setting the scroll to true however it does not effect the spacing between chips. I have added an image to the original post to indicate the spacing I am looking to reduce.

Comment: I don't know how much you use of the chips, but maybe consider making your own?